# paging of datacontrol in jquery dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm using Jquery dialogs in my Asp.net web application for all my messages.
Now I've tried to fill a listview with customers inside a dialog and its working, but I want to allow the user to use paging in the listview for choosing his customer out of the list.
When I press the button to move up 1 page, it ain't working...

Maybe it's just not possible? Or does someone have an example of paging a datacontrol in a Jquery dialog?

Greetz,
Ben

Comment: Could you post some code please?

Comment: If I understand, the paging links aren't working correctly within the dialog?

Comment: At first they wouldn't postback, but I've solved that problem.
The only problem I had was showing the dialog with the listview after postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the dialog is not being displayed after the paging postback?

You have two options:

One: Change to using a popup window with the listview so that the paging is handled in the normal way in its own page

Two: On the serverside, when rendering pages, also render a startup jQuery script that re-displays the dialog.

```
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none;"  >
        <asp:listview ID="lv" runat="server" />
        ...etc
    </div>
```

In code behind:

```
        var script = new StringBuilder();
        script.AppendLine("jQuery(function($) {");
        script.AppendLine(string.Format("    $('#dialog').attr('Title','{0}');",  dialogTitle));
        script.AppendLine("    $('#dialog').dialog({ closeOnEscape: true,  modal: true });");
        script.AppendLine("});");

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "dialog", script.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd option works!
I only added this code in codebehind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "openDialogScript", "$(function() { openCustomerDialog(); });", true);
```

And in the .aspx file I added this:

```
openCustomerDialog = function openDialog(){
    $("#reportCustomerDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,           
        height: 420,
        width: 500,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dialog").show();   
};
```